# "Pinning" nodes in a D3 force-directed graph

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, force-layout, pinning

I have constructed a regular "grid" that places nodes at evenly-spaced points across the grid. Then, by randomizing the linkDistance, I'm able to "stir up" the grid so it's less regular.

I'd like to "pin" all the edge points such that they don't move - leaving only the inner points to be affected by the force layout.

My insight was that since this is a regular quad grid, any points with a weight less than 4 would be an "edge" point, and thus should be pinned.

I figure that weight is only calculated after the nodes and links have been added to the force layout, so I'm `forEach`ing through the `nodes` array, after adding it to the force layout, and conditionally setting the `fixed` property based on weight.

Then, I'm reapplying the `nodes` property and `start`ing the simulation.

No good. In the example I'm attaching ALL the points move.

```
force = d3.layout.force()
                .size( [w, h ] )
                .nodes( nodes )
                .links( links )
                .linkDistance( function( d ){ return Math.random() * GRID_SPACING; } )
                .linkStrength( 1 )
                .charge( 0 )
                .gravity( 0 )
                .friction( .5 )
                .on( "tick", function() {
                    d3links.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

                    d3nodes.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
                        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
                } );

            // "Pin" all the edge nodes.
            nodes.forEach( function( node ){
                if ( node.weight < 4 ){
                    node.fixed = true;
                }
            } );

            force.nodes( nodes ).start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your insight is a good one!  But timing is everything...
The "start" event is triggered after the weights have been initialised so this should work...

```
force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([w, h])
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .linkDistance(function (d) { return Math.random() * GRID_SPACING; })
    .linkStrength(1)
    .charge(0)
    .gravity(0)
    .friction(.5)
    .on("tick", function () {
        d3links.attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
                .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
                .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
                .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });

        d3nodes.attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
                .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; });
    })
    .on("start", function () {
        // "Pin" all the edge nodes.
        nodes.forEach(function (node) {
            if (node.weight < 4) {
                node.fixed = true;
            }
        });
    })


force.nodes(nodes).start();
```

(If you want to include drag behavior then you would need to re-fix after dragend also.)

Comment: That did it! So I'm guessing that weights are not calculated until after the force layout is actually started. In my code, I wasn't starting the layout so weights were all undefined, and so none of the nodes were meeting my "pinning" criteria. It's strange that it wasn't throwing an error.

Comment: No need to guess @TomAuger just read the d3 code, its quite straight forward in that module. ;)